# Redirecting on click with php

Tags: php, html, mysqli

What i need help with is when someone choose which CRN (course number),

I need to direct them to another page or form and save the button clicked as a value. (redirect and send the clicked value to that page)

[image: Table]

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                  <thead>
                    <tr style="background-color:#f2f2f2">
                      <th>CRN</th>
                      <th>Section</th>
                      <th>Course Title</th>
                      <th>Start Time</th>
                      <th>End Time</th>
                      <th>Room Number</th>
                    </tr>

                    <?php $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'mydb');
                    if ($db-> connect_error){
                      die("connection_failed:".$db-> connect_error);
                    }

                    $sql ="SELECT CRN, section, Crse_Title, Crse_Start_Time, Crse_End_Time, Room_Num from section";
                    $result = $db -> query($sql);

                    if($result -> num_rows > 0){
                      while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
                        echo "<tr>
                              <td><button class='btn btn-md' type='submit' name='section-submit'>".$row["CRN"]."</button></td>
                              <td>". $row["section"]. "</td>
                              <td>". $row["Crse_Title"]. "</td>
                              <td>". $row["Crse_Start_Time"]."</td>
                              <td>". $row["Crse_End_Time"]."</td>
                              <td>". $row["Room_Num"]."</td>
                              </tr>";
                      }
                      echo "</table>";
                    }
                    else {
                      echo "0 result";
                    }
                    $db -> close();
                    ?>
                  </thead>
                </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I could not understand you completely.
However, I intend to help you.
What do i think you need:

*Redirect the user to another page with the clicked value*

**Your Table file :**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr style="background-color:#f2f2f2">
            <th>CRN</th>
            <th>Section</th>
            <th>Course Title</th>
            <th>Start Time</th>
            <th>End Time</th>
            <th>Room Number</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'mydb');
        if($db->connect_error)
        {
            die("connection_failed:".$db->connect_error);
        }
        $sql="SELECT CRN, section, Crse_Title, Crse_Start_Time, Crse_End_Time, Room_Num from section";
        $result = $db->query($sql);
        if($result->num_rows > 0)
        {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
            {
                echo "<tr>
                            <td><a href='course.php?id=".$row["CRN"]."' class='btn btn-md'>".$row["CRN"]."</a></td>
                            <td>". $row["section"]. "</td>
                            <td>". $row["Crse_Title"]. "</td>
                            <td>". $row["Crse_Start_Time"]."</td>
                            <td>". $row["Crse_End_Time"]."</td>
                            <td>". $row["Room_Num"]."</td>
                            </tr>";
            }
            //echo "</table>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "0 result";
        }
        $db->close();
        ?>
    </thead>
</table>
```

**Course file :**

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
//is_numeric()
$id=(int) $_GET['id'];
print "Current Course ID : " . $id;
}
?>
```

There are other ways too.( such as : Writing JavaScript code )

Comment: I suggest you add `(int)` to the GET array, otherwise it's open to sql injection if used in another query. Although a prepared statement is preferred, `(int)` if it will always be an integer, will help against one.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know the details of that project. However, I thank you for mentioning it.